# Does PHP str_replace have a greater than 13 character limit?

Tags: php, compiler-errors, str-replace

This works up until the 13th character is hit. Once the str_ireplace hits "a" in the cyper array, the str_ireplace stops working.

Is there a limit to how big the array can be? Keep in mind if type "abgf" i get "nots", but if I type "abgrf" when I should get "notes" I get "notrs". Racked my brain cant figure it out.

```
$_cypher = array("n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m");

$_needle = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z");


$_decryptedText = str_ireplace($_cypher, $_needle, $_text);
echo $_decryptedText;
```

Help?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`strtr`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$_text = 'abgrf';

$translate = array_combine($_cypher, $_needle);

$_decryptedText = strtr($_text, $translate);

echo $_decryptedText; # notes
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/L0qudk)

---

> But, was there something I was doing wrong?

It will replace each pair, one pair after the other on the already replaced string. So if you replace a character that you replace again, this can happen:

```
    r -> e   e -> r
abgrf -> notes -> notrs
```

Your e-replacement comes after your r-replacement.

Comment: Ah. So like @ircmaxell said, it's doing a circular replacement. Is other than using str_rot13 is there a way to complete the task as I have it?

Comment: @Firemarble: As written `strtr`. I added an example.

Answer (score 2):

Take a peak at the docs for [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace).  Namely the following line:

> Because str_replace() replaces left to right, it might replace a previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements. See also the examples in this document.

So it's working as told.  It's just doing a circular replacement (n -> a, then a -> n).

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_rot13](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php)

Comment: Thanks, that works. But, was there something I was doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

although it appears to be a straight rot13, if it is not, another option is to use [strtr()](http://www.php.net/strtr). You provide a string and an array of replacement pairs and get the resulting translation back.