# htmlspecialchars to only convert greater (>) and lesser (<) signs

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I want to use htmlspecialchars but to only convert the greater (>) and lesser (<) signs. I do not want to convert the single, double and '&' signs. I tried and searched alot but could not find the answer. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? Can you explain why? Raw ampersands are invalid HTML

Answer (score 2):

```
$replace = array('<' => '&lt;', '>' => '&gt;');
$string=strtr($string, $replace);
```

Differences between [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [strtr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) are discussed here: [When to use strtr vs str_replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177296/when-to-use-strtr-vs-str-replace)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a str_replace() function with an array as 'needle in the haystack':

```
$search_for_lt = array("<","&lt;");
$string = str_replace($search_for_lt, "replacement here, can be empty", $string);
$search_for_gt = array(">","&lt;");
$string = str_replace($search_for_gt, "replacement here, can be empty", $string);
```

Can you confirm it is working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just replace only those characters using [str_replace](http://www.php.net/str_replace) then?

```
$result = str_replace(['<', '>'], ['&lt;', '&gt;'], $string);
```