# Use numeric literals with an array in PHP (preg_replace)

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace, numeric, literals

I'm trying to use numeric literals with my array $test with preg_replace in PHP, there is what I got:

```
$test["a"] = "hey";

// Find a as $0
echo preg_replace("/[a-z]/", "Found:$0", "a")."\n";

// Can replace it by "hey"
echo preg_replace("/[a-z]/", $test['a'], "a")."\n";

// Can't replace it :/
echo preg_replace("/[a-z]/", $test["$0"], "a")."\n";
```

As you see, the last preg_replace function doesn't work, whereas the two others work fine... I tried a lot of times to include the $0 with various tricks, but nothing stills work... Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) :

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/[a-z]/", function ($b) use ($test) {
    return $test[$b[0]];
}, "a")."\n";
```

With more tests :

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/[a-z]/", function ($b) use ($test) {
    if (isset($b[0]) && isset($test[$b[0]]))
        return $test[$b[0]];
    return "";
}, "a")."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current use case does not require regex, you can (and should if possible) use `strtr` or `str_replace` depending on what the requirements are:

```
$test["a"] = "hey";
$test["b"] = "you";

echo strtr("a b", $test); //hey you

echo str_replace(array_keys($test), array_values($test), "a b"); //hey you
```

Refer to [When to use strtr vs str_replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177296/when-to-use-strtr-vs-str-replace) on what the differences are.