# PHP Use Regex match as key from POST array for replacement

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I have these variables:

```
$summary="The problem with field2 is field13.  The fix will be field7"
$_POST['field2']='thiscomputer';
$_POST['field7']='thishotfix';
$_POST['field13']='thisapplication';
```

I'm trying to craft a preg_replace() that will find /field[0-9]/ within the string and replace it with the value from the $_POST array.  But I keep coming up short. Maybe preg_replace() is the wrong function to use in this instance.
I'm trying to replace an old long list of 50+ str_replace's

Thanks for any help that can point me in the right direction

Comment: preg_replace is the way to go, but nowhere in your example is the string `POST1`. That might be your problem right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this single line `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace`? *You may need to fix some spacing*, that can be resolved by the array value

```
echo str_replace(array_keys($_POST),array_values($_POST),$summary);
```

**Output:**

```
The problem with thiscomputer is thisapplication.  The fix will be thishotfix
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/quYVO

Comment: @eagers glad it helps you somehow :)

Answer (score 1):

`strtr`, though I'd probably want to copy and filter that post array:

```
<?php

$summary="The problem with field2 is field13.  The fix will be field7";
$_POST['field2']='thiscomputer';
$_POST['field7']='thishotfix';
$_POST['field13']='thisapplication';

echo strtr($summary, $_POST);
```

Output:

```
The problem with thiscomputer is thisapplication.  The fix will be thishotfix
```

Comment: Note strtr and str_replace slightly differ in the way they substitute.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177296/when-to-use-strtr-vs-str-replace

Comment: Have a look here the benchmark https://simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=175031.0

Comment: This does indeed work, but since I am replacing old str_replace code, sticking with a new str_replace method works better for my team. Still Thank you!